How can I use json data in listview.builder in flutter
I'm getting a json response like this:
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "CTID": "5",
            "City": "Hatkanangle",
            "Status": "1"
        },
        {
            "CTID": "6",
            "City": "Sangli",
            "Status": "1"
        },
        {
            "CTID": "7",
            "City": "Ichalkaranji",
            "Status": "1"
        },
        {
            "CTID": "8",
            "City": "Shirol",
            "Status": "1"
        }
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "message": "data found!"
}

How can I use this data in listview builder?
I want to display a list of cities; after selecting a city, in the  onPressed event handler, I want to save id of the particular city in a variable.

Firstly, create a class model file city_model.dart
class City {
  final String ctid;
  final String name;
  final String status;

  City({required this.ctid, required this.name, required this.status});

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return City(
      ctid: json['CTID'] as String,
      name: json['City'] as String,
      status: json['Status'] as String,
    );
  }
}

Use this to decode json data and implement in listview.builder
  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(jsonData); //jsonData is your json response
        var cityList = (map['cities'] as List)
            .map((value) => City.fromJson(value))
            .toList(); 

    //And then add it to listview.builder

  ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cityList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final city = cityList[index];
          
        return ListTile(
            title: Text(city.name),
            subtitle: Text('ID: ${city.ctid}, Status: ${city.status}'),
            onTap: () {
               // val = city.ctid; 
           },
           ),
        },
  );


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

We can also do using this way
First create empty list
List<dynamic> cities = [];

Then decode jsondata using json.decode. Simply add this two line code in initState
final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonData);
cities = data['cities'];

Then after you can use cities list in ListView.builder
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cities.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var cityName = cities[index]['City'];
                  return Text('$cityName');
                },
            )


First you need to create a model:
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final cityResponseModel = cityResponseModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

CityResponseModel cityResponseModelFromJson(String str) => CityResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String cityResponseModelToJson(CityResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CityResponseModel {
    List<City> cities;
    int status;
    String message;

    CityResponseModel({
        required this.cities,
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
    });

    factory CityResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CityResponseModel(
        cities: List<City>.from(json["cities"].map((x) => City.fromJson(x))),
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cities": List<dynamic>.from(cities.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
    };
}

class City {
    String ctid;
    String city;
    String status;

    City({
        required this.ctid,
        required this.city,
        required this.status,
    });

    factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => City(
        ctid: json["CTID"],
        city: json["City"],
        status: json["Status"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "CTID": ctid,
        "City": city,
        "Status": status,
    };
}

Then your page like this:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key,});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  CityResponseModel cityResponse=CityResponseModel(cities: [], status: 0, message: "");
  City? selectedCity ;
  void fetchData() {
    setState(() {
      //fetch city list here
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
       
        title: Text("City"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount:  cityResponse.cities.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              //You must change with your logics
            selectedCity=cityResponse.cities[index];
            });
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(cityResponse.cities[index].city),
              Text(cityResponse.cities[index].ctid),
              Text(cityResponse.cities[index].status),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
  }
}

